Looking for a way to set up GitAhead with automatic dark/light mode
Since there is no inbuild theme switcher (there are only two options "Default" and "Dark"), I was wondering if there is another way to get it switch automatically. I use it a lot so it would be nice to have this feature. :)
I am using Windows so maybe there is a way to access the registry keys automatically?
I looked for a solution using Google but could not find any.
